# How deep should logging go?

Tags: java, validation, logging

To paint a scenario, consider the following *logic-omitted-Service*

```
public class Service {
   private Validator validator;

   public void submit(Foo foo) {
      if (!validator.isValid(foo)) {
         log.warn("invalid foo");
      } ...
   }
}
```

```
public interface Validator {
   boolean isValid(Foo foo);
}
```

The problem is that **only** the `Validor` itself knows the *reason* to why the validation would fail. I see only two viable approaches to tuning in on that *reason*. Either the `Validator`

- logs the failing condition itself
- returns a complex object containing a String **reason** and boolean **isValid**.

The former is nice but would leave the `Service` clueless to whether logging is actually performed, and the latter introduces an annoying redudancy and a more complex usage.

Which is to prefer, or, is there a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to ask yourself a question: do your client care about the validation failure reason? And the answer is: *it depends*. In many cases you would like to inform the end user precisely what was the cause of validation failure. In that case return "complex" validation result object (don't use exceptions here!), essentially wrapping a collection of strings or codes (to allow [i18n](/questions/tagged/i18n)). The `ValidationResult` object would be a business object, not some second-class helper.

In other situations you just want to make a decision based on whether the object was valid or not. The calling code (client) couldn't care less about the internal logic of validation. It's either valid or not. Then go for straight `boolean` method. For debug purposes add logging inside validation method. Turn them on/off depending on your desire.

And you know what's the best part? You can have two methods and use whichever suits better for the client code. Obviously the less complicated `boolean` method only delegates to more compilcated one and provides simpler *view*:

```
boolean isValid(Foo foo) {
    validate(foo).isValid();
}

ValidationResult validate(Foo foo) {
    //logging and "real" validation
}
```

Comment: An insightful answer. In particular, does the service *need* to pass on a reason or not.